# Image size should not vary in android devices

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-imageview

I am having an image in imageview of size 5.64mm.
As android having different resolution,image is varying for different devices.
In my case image should not vary at any device.
please help me with some code for drawing the image or setting the imageview Fixed size.

Answer (score 1):

you have to create the same image for different resolutions and put those images in the hdpi,xhdpi etc folders.
Lets assume your image is 100 x 100 in pixel size, so a device with 320 x 480 pixel will show it big but a device with 1280 x 800 will display your picture smaller.
In other words the more pixels a device has in its per square inch space the smaller space your icon will take.
so you have to create multiple versions of your image so that it size remains relatively same.

Answer (score 0):

Do this way. Use dp unit to specify height and width.

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageThumb"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/icms_white"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Answer (score -1):

use

```
android:layout_width="5.64mm"
android:layout_width="6.15mm"
```

Comment: This also not working,image size is varying for different devices.:(